# When to use definite article? Like "la" and "el"

Tags: gramática, artículos

This is one of those differences between English and Spanish. Although for the most part where is definite article is not used in English, it is probably not used in Spanish, due to my lack of reading, I get unsure sometimes as to whether I should use definite article.

Like when I say

> My sister does the homework for me. 
>   Mi hermana hace **la** tarea por mi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some situations in which you need to use the definite article include:

1. The article precedes the noun, even if there is an adjetive in between.

> El coche. La raqueta. El asombroso trapecista. El milagroso elixir

But never when it precedes the names of people or places

2. It can precede the name of people or places when (**and only when**) it is used to qualify them,

> La España de la edad media (but never *La España*). El general López (but never *El López*)

Be aware that some places have the article included in the name, such as *El Salvador*, *La Habana*, etc.

This includes *titles* of people

> El rey. El Papa. La condesa.

and days of the week and languages

> El lunes. El martes. El español. El noruego.

3. When referring to individuals of a group.

> Los niños tienen que ir al colegio. El delfín es un animal inteligente

4. When referring to abstract beings or entities, in a general meaning.

> La paciencia es una virtud.

This includes verbs used as subjects

> El esperar tanto tiempo se hace pesado. El pasear es un hábito saludable (although this could be easily omitted)

Comment: But you can certainly use articles with names.  But depending on the region, I believe it can have different connotations.  For me it implies a level of familiarity between me, the person I'm speaking to, and the person I'm talking about.  "Sabes que el Juan …" = I know Juan well, and so does the person I'm speaking.  It can also be used to specify a particular person with a given name, as in "Juan dijo…"  "¿Juan?"  "El Juan de la tienda".

Comment: @guifa, Thanks for pointing it. I had in mind that catalans do that (I actually didn't know it is the case in Asturias too). You are definitely right about that, but in Madrid saying something like that would sound really weird, so I would include it as a regional variation, not as a general rule.

Comment: Oh I totally used it all the time in Madrid (my interest in Asturias came later). But it was mainly jocular "Sabes que el Juan ese ..." (I'm about to make fun of him). I know in some parts of LA it is relatively common. The DPD says it's even in formal registers in Chile.

Comment: But I agree it's not generalized. I'd just say "not normally used" rather than never :-)

Comment: @guifa, wait, that can be tricky. It could be understood as something pejorative "El Juan ese..." like "El Gutiérrez es que no sabe ni hacer la 'o' con un canuto"; "Ya está el Rajoy otra vez con sus discursitos". Mmm, maybe is more used than what I thought, but with a different inflection in different areas.

Comment: Barring the case of Chile @guifa mentions, use of the article in front of people names is either pejorative, as Diego remarks, or vulgar (i.e. incorrect). It is a usual incorrection in Catalan speakers because it is mandatory in Catalan, as it is in other languages, such as Portuguese.

Comment: Additionally, some place names always take the article (rivers, mountains, seas...). And there are some country names that can take it or not: you can say *el Perú*, *la Argentina*, *el Brasil* or *la China*, though the article is not mandatory at all and I would say its use is declining.

Comment: @Gorpik, you are right. Interestingly, the example I could think of was "La India" but I would not have referred to Perú or Argentina with an article (I would for China "Vete a la China").

Comment: Indeed, *India* is maybe the best example: it is almost always *la India*, even though the article is not part of the country name. Some other countries where you can use the article are *el Uruguay*, *el Paraguay* or *el Canadá*. And, of course, country names which include common nouns usually take the article: *los Estados Unidos*, *el Reino Unido*, *la República Checa*...

Answer (score 1):

When you use a definite article (the), you are doing exactly what the article is described to do; DEFINE.

```
I look at the chair / Miro la silla
```

vs

```
I look at a chair / Miro una silla
```

The second sentence suggests that there is more than one chair, while the first sentence defines a particular chair.  Typically, when you use a definite article you will also use more adjectives to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understood your question, but there is absolutely no difference in the definite / indefinite distinction between English and Spanish.

> A policeman = Un policía
>
> The policeman = El policía

Answer (score 0):

el comaBeware some cases where the article is necessary to change the meaning.. for example

```
 la policía (the police - police department)
 el policía (the policeman)
 el guía (the guide)
 la guía (the driver)
 el cólera (the cholera)
 la cólera (the anger)
 el capital (the capital/money)
 la capital (the capital/city)
 el orden (things in order)
 la orden (command/order)
 el cura (priest)
 la cura (therapy)
 el coma (coma - medicine)
 la coma (comma "," punctuation mark)
 el cometa (comet)
 la cometa (kite)
 el margen (edge)
 la margen (bank of river)
```

Comment: La definición de 'el coma' que das no la había escuchado nunca, de hecho ni siquiera aparece en el diccionario de la RAE. Otro significado podría ser: "Estado patológico que se caracteriza por la pérdida de la conciencia, la sensibilidad y la capacidad motora voluntaria."

Answer (score -1):

There are many uses for definite article so please [read this link](http://spanish.about.com/od/adjectives/a/intro_def_art.htm).

One of the most important rule is that you can use definite articles when referring to objects, people, and places.

Here are some examples:

> La comida de México es deliciosa. (Mexican food is delicious.)
>
> Las películas de Almodóvar son interesantes. (Almodóvar´s movies are interesting.)

Comment: This rule does not exist. You can also use the indefinite article to refer to people, objects and places: _Ayer vimos **unas** películas de Almodóvar_, versus _me gustan **las** películas de Almodóvar_.